How do I fit an exponential 3D surface to measured data
This is my data:
[[1.0183786345931547, 1.0299586760768078, 1.038641346963767, 1.0450398412805133, 1.194598528164483], [1.0498980141678536, 1.0740481275807727, 1.101990429736493, 1.1528998376687427, 1.4439775675193383], [1.072406763443829, 1.150808521648661, 1.2306731013044911, 1.3516512408949992, 1.8936625169205694]]

and this is the plot code:
J4 = [0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7]
d = [0.25,0.333333,0.5]

Data = np.array(data).transpose()
x, y = np.meshgrid(d,J4)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,10))
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.scatter(x, y, Data, s=40, alpha=1)
ax.set_proj_type('ortho')

plt.tight_layout()

I want to fit an exponential surface to it such that I can both plot it along the scatter and also get the equation for the surface.
Click here to see the scatter plot

A quick and dirty approximation might be to assume that it is separable and fit exponentials to each of the slices. Then use that model to look at the residuals after subtracting that very simple model to see if there are any cross term residuals.

With the dataset provided:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

x = np.array([0.25, 0.333333, 0.5])
y = np.array([0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = np.array([
    [1.0183786345931547, 1.0299586760768078, 1.038641346963767, 1.0450398412805133, 1.194598528164483],
    [1.0498980141678536, 1.0740481275807727, 1.101990429736493, 1.1528998376687427, 1.4439775675193383],
    [1.072406763443829, 1.150808521648661, 1.2306731013044911, 1.3516512408949992, 1.8936625169205694]
]).T

We can hypothesize the following model:
def model(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b * x[0] ** 2 * np.exp(c * x[1])

We perform the regression:
r = np.vstack([
    X.ravel(),
    Y.ravel()
])
z = Z.ravel()

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, r, z)

The score is about:
zhat = model(r, *popt)
score = r2_score(z, zhat) # 0.9746146254532012

Which is not too bad for an unknown model.
Visually, the fit renders as follow:
xlin = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 50)
ylin = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 50)
Xlin, Ylin = np.meshgrid(xlin, ylin)
rlin = np.vstack([
    Xlin.ravel(),
    Ylin.ravel()
])
zlin = model(rlin, *popt)
Zlin = zlin.reshape(Xlin.shape)

fig, axe = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
axe.scatter(X, Y, Z)
axe.plot_surface(Xlin, Ylin, Zlin, alpha=0.3, cmap="jet")
axe.contour(Xlin, Ylin, Zlin, 10, cmap="jet")



Stop using jet. Use one of the perceptually uniform maps like viridis.

Thank you very much. How do I get the regression coefficients tho?

They are contained in the variable pcov.
